# How to fill a column with the numbers of third column associated to the strings of fourth column in Unix environment?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a TAB file something like

```
342455  94387   94387   YY1AP1 
                        YY1AP1 
        141675  141675  LAMTOR2
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
                        NRDC    
        352178  352178  NRDC   
                        NRDC       
        352178  352178  NRDC    
        352178  352178  NRDC    
                        NRDC      
                311380  MPC2
                311380  MPC2
                        MPC2
```

and I would like to fill in the first column for every row with the numbers of third column according to the fourth column. Moreover those rows are empty should be filled too with the same number corresponding to fourth column. So, the desired output should be:

```
342455  94387   94387   YY1AP1 
342455                  YY1AP1 
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
352178                  NRDC    
352178  352178  352178  NRDC   
352178                  NRDC       
352178  352178  352178  NRDC    
352178  352178  352178  NRDC    
352178                  NRDC      
311380          311380  MPC2
311380          311380  MPC2
311380                  MPC2
```

In this way I have tried to do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } {if ($1 == "") { $1 = $3 } else if ($1 ~/^[0-9]/){ $1 = $1 }} print}' "input.tsv" > "output.tsv";
```

Nevertheless, only fill the first column if there is a number in third column. I think to create a hash in order to relate third and fourth column and then associate it to first column and get the desired output but, are there any possibility to do this in a more simple way? Thanks in advance.

Ok. The output obtained by means of your script @RavinderSingh13 is something like:

```
342455  94387   94387   YY1AP1
YY1AP1                  YY1AP1
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
NRDC                    NRDC
352178  352178  352178  NRDC
NRDC                    NRDC
352178  352178  352178  NRDC
352178  352178  352178  NRDC
NRDC                    NRDC
311380          311380  MPC2
311380          311380  MPC2
MCP2                    MPC2
```

Do the same function that I want but print the 4th column on 1st column instead of 3rd column

Comment: Could you please do let us know why column filling is not consistent? And moreover it is not clear at least to me like which ever fields should be filed, you mentioned field 1 but I can see many are getting filled, please do let us know the logic so that we could help you.

Comment: Ok. So I want to write only the first column with the numbers of third column and each number in third column is associated to one string in fourth column. In this way, when the third column is empty, I would like to write in first column the number associated to the fourth column since in all cases the strings in fourth column are at least associated to a number in third column in one row. My script only write first column if there is a number in third column

Comment: Why on 5th line you are filling all the columns and not on 7th line where NRDC is there ?

Comment: You are right. Is an error when I have performed the output. Now is corrected. Thanks @RavinderSingh13

Comment: The first row is embarrassing me: `342455  94387   94387   YY1AP1`. Why first and third columns different? Also, second row in the desired output have the `342455` number in the first column too, when, according to your logic, it should have `94387`, because the `94387` number is associated with `YY1AP1` string in the fourth column.

Comment: In fact for 1st row the second and third column are wrong. Should be 342455. Thanks @MiniMax

Comment: So in fact for 1st row the second and third column are different. But is right. For some rows the 3rd column are different respect to the 1st column. in this case have priority 1st column. In summary there are three cases. If first column have a number, remain constant. If 1st column are empty and 3rd column have a number, print this one on 1st column. If 1st, 2nd and 3rd column are empty, print on 1st the same number according to the 4th column in other row @MiniMax. After check the file I have verified that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F'\t' '
FNR == NR {
    if(!arr[$4])
        arr[$4] = ($1) ? $1 : $3;
}
FNR != NR {
    if(!$1)
        printf "%d", arr[$4];
    print;
}' input.txt input.txt
```

Comment: Does work correctly. However I want to generate an output, but I'm not sure how do it because writing input.txt > output.txt or gawk -i inplace does not work both

Comment: @PercevalVellosilloGonzalez For writing the output to the file, change last line to the  `}' input.txt input.txt > output.txt`. Should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping @MiniMax.

Answer (score 1):

++ve for good question, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you, also if you are not bothered about spacing(else I could fix it too then).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$0;
  if(!/^ +[a-zA-Z]+/){
    sub(/^ +/,"",val);
    num=split(val, a," ");
    b[$NF]=a[1]
};
  if(/^[0-9]+/){
    b[$NF]=$1
};
  next
}
/^[0-9]+/{
  print;
  next
}
!/^[0-9]+/{
  print b[$NF],$0
}
'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
342455  94387   94387   YY1AP1
342455                         YY1AP1
141675         141675  141675  LAMTOR2
141675  141675  141675  LAMTOR2
352178                         NRDC
352178         352178  352178  NRDC
352178                         NRDC
352178         352178  352178  NRDC
352178         352178  352178  NRDC
352178                         NRDC
311380                 311380  MPC2
311380                 311380  MPC2
311380                         MPC2
```

Comment: does not work correctly. The output obtained is similar. When there is a number within 3rd column, print the same in 1st column. However, when the 3rd column is empty, print the 4th column instead of 3rd column

Comment: Could you please edit your post with these details, I will try to fix it then.

Comment: I have written on the top as well as on both posts more in detail the output performed by your script and why does not work correctly. Thanks anyway @RavinderSingh13 for helping and suggestions all the time

Comment: how come it is possible, it is working fine for me, could you please check if you have any carriage characters in your Input_file, by doing cat -v Input_file if yes then remove it by doing tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: I have done cat -v to my file but does not appear nothing more besides the same text

Comment: I tested my script again and it is working fine for me. Are you using same Input_file not sure what's going on

Comment: Works correctly. In fact I suppose does not work in my case because the file contains more columns after the 4th column